# How to replace values in all pandas rows by list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list:

```
a = [a,te,re,edf,c,sa,da,wq,rw...]
```

And DF 5888 len:

```
name  sex snps1 snps2 snps3 snps4 ... snps338
aas   M    a     te    re    dd   ... ...
aab   M    a     ga    re    af   ... ...
...
```

I need to replace  values based on list.

First value in list is first SNPS for dataframe etc. So I need to compare first value in list with whole column "snps1". And replace values on True/False.

Expected result:

```
  name  sex snps1 snps2 snps3 snps4 ... snps338
 sample1   M  TRUE  TRUE   TRUE  FALSE   ... ...
 sample2   M  TRUE  FALSE  TRUE  FALSE   ... ...
     ...
```

I wrote a code:

two for loop. First for j in len(list), second for df len, and if statements... but it means that i will be looped 5888x338 times. And it takes too much time.

How can I do it in better way? I tried found a solution but all founded posts didn't fit for my problem.

Can somoeone help mi with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html), for example:

```
import pandas as pd


data = [['aas', 'M', 'a', 'te', 're', 'dd'],
        ['aab', 'M', 'a', 'ga', 're', 'af']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['name', 'sex', 'snps1', 'snps2', 'snps3', 'snps4'])

a = ['a', 'te', 're', 'edf', 'c', 'sa', 'da', 'wq', 'rw']
columns = ['snps1', 'snps2', 'snps3', 'snps4']

lookup = { key : (value,) for key, value in zip(columns, a) }
df.loc[:, columns] = df.loc[:, columns].isin(lookup)
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
  name sex snps1  snps2 snps3  snps4
0  aas   M  True   True  True  False
1  aab   M  True  False  True  False
```

Comment: @DanielMesejo, If I understood the problem correctly, this solution is not going to take care of the proper order of comparision. Meaning, snps1 should only compare against a[0], snps2 should only compare against a[1], and so on.

Comment: @martin I have provided a solution below which would take care of the comparison against proper value from the list.

Comment: @san is correct. I have provided an updated version that still uses isin

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have the dataframe 'df' and the list 'a' already created, this would do:

```
for index, val in enumerate(a):
    colname="snps"+str(index+1)
    df[colname]=df[colname].astype(str)==val
```